# How to choose between Google Noto emoji black and white, versus color, icon?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, emoji, google-fonts

Why is the emoji in the code below sometimes shown as colored and sometimes as black and white please? And how do I make it consistent - so I can choose between whichever I want?

```js
document.getElementById('m').innerHTML = '\u{1F600}';
```

```css
emo { font-family: 'Noto Emoji', sans-serif; }
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="true">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Emoji&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<br />
<br />
<span class="emo">&#x1F600</span>
<br />
<br />
<span id='m' class="emo"></span>
<br />
<br />
<select name="" id="">
            <option ><span class="emo">&#x1F600</span></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [variation selectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_(Unicode_block)) after a codepoint to control if an glyph should display emoji-style (like ️) or monochrome style (︎). How glyphs are rendered if no variant selection is specified varies among text renderers, in practice.

You can use U+FE0E (VARIATION SELECTOR-15) to force text style, and U+FE0F (VARIATION SELECTOR-16) to force emoji style:

```html
Emoji style: &#xFE0F; <br>
Text style: &#xFE0E;
```